# Way to Capture result set from instead of insert trigger in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, triggers, output

I have a table that utilizes an instead of insert trigger.  The trigger manipulates the data for each inserted row before inserting it.  Because the inserted table is not modifiable, it was implemented using a temp (#) table.  At the end of the trigger a select from the temp table is done to return the inserted data to the calling client.  When I do a an insert in SSMS, I can see the data that is returned and the columns all have names and values. My Trigger looks like this:

```
Create   TRIGGER [dbo].[RealTableInsteadOfInsert] on [dbo].[RealTable]
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
    set nocount on;
    declare @lastDigit int;
    if exists (select * from inserted)
    Begin

        Select * 
        into #tempInserted
        from inserted

        .... Logic to add and manipulate column data .....

        INSERT INTO RealTAble(id, col1, col2, col3,....)
            Select *
            from #tempInserted;

        Select id as insertId,  *
        from #tempInserted;
    END
End
```

My question is how can I capture the output of the instead of trigger into a table for further processing using the returned data. I can't use an output clause on the insert statement as the temp table no longer exists and the data that was calculated/modified on the insert was not done in the inserted table. Is my only option to update the trigger to use a global temp table instead of a local?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options:

1. Send data through service broker. This is complicated and potentially slow. On the plus side, it does let you do your further processing work decoupled from the original transaction, which is nice in certain use cases.
2. Write the data to a real table. This *can* also give you transactional decoupling, but you don't get automatic activation of the decoupled processing logic if you want that.

OK, but if you write to a real table, and a lot of processes are causing the trigger to fire, how do you find "your" data? Putting aside the fact that a global temp table has the same problem unless you want to get dynamic, one solution is to use a process keyed table, as described by Erland Sommarskog in his [data sharing article](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#prockeyed).

Returning data from triggers (ie, to a client) is a *bad* idea. The ability to do this at all will [soon be removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/disallow-results-from-triggers-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) I know you don't need to do this in your solution, just giving you a heads up.